# How to express about getting informed about a specific position

Tags: mathematics, application, postdocs, application-cover-letter

I am going to prepare a cover letter for postdoc position. I was informed about this position by my Phd advisor. I am looking for a proper statement about how I was informed about such that position, which must be express usually at the initial paragraph of a cover letter. May you please tell me how would be a good statement for this type of info.

Comment: Why do you have to express this in the letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason to express where you learned about a job advertisement, except if it was emailed *personally* to from whoever you learned about it, and not widely distributed. However, usually these are mass emails sent to a large number of people (recognizable by several factors). In that sense, I don't see any reason why you would need to state how you learned about the position - unless you want to make a point out of it, i.e. make it clear to Prof. X who advertised the job that their good friend Prof. Y (or maybe the very famous Prof. Z) suggested to *you personally* that you should apply, which hopefully reflects positively on you in the eyes of Prof. X.

Comment: Don't include 'who is a good friend of yours'. If Prof X *is* my friend, I don't need to be reminded. If Prof X isn't someone I regard as 'a good friend', this just sounds weird.

Comment: @avid That's why I said "indicating" - my point is that the OP maybe wants to *indicate* what I say in the quote. Not *write* this literally. And indeed, the square bracket part was meant *not* to be written in the letter by any means. I assumed this to be clear to anyone reasonable. (I mean ... seriously?)